# regex behavior in find

Tags: regex, bash, find

I'm trying to use find to

match repos with the name hello that pass through a regex expression, removing the ones with `github.com` in them. When I try and run my command:

```
find ~ -type d -name hello -regex "^((?!github.com).)*$"
```

It gives me 
`-bash: !github.com: event not found`.

running `find ~ -type d -name hello` gives me:

```
/home/retep/repos/gofun/src/hello
/home/retep/repos/course-golang-fork/src/hello
/home/retep/repos/hello
/home/retep/repos/hello/go/src/hello
/home/retep/repos/hello/go/src/hello/hello
/home/retep/go/src/github.com/retep-mathwizard/fun/go/src/hello
/home/retep/repos/hello/go/pkg/linux_amd64/hello
/home/retep/extra/rango/src/github.com/retep-mathwizard/fun/go/src/hello
/home/retep/extra/rango/src/hello
/home/retep/extra/rango/src/hello/hello
/home/retep/extra/rango/pkg/linux_amd64/hello
```

Comment: You have history expansion on so `!` is interpreted. You can use single quotes to prevent that. Your regex still won't work though, since lookarounds are not supported.

Comment: Also can you give an example of paths you want matched/not matched ?

Comment: I added it @123

Comment: So you want to remove ones with `github.com` in them, regardless of where it occurs?

Comment: ------------yes

Comment: So why not just `-regex '.*github.com.*'`, or if what you mean is you don't want to match them then `! -regex '.*github.com.*'`,

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew name only matches the base.

Comment: that worked for me @123